# How change numbering table just in one chapter?

Tags: tables, numbering, counters

I have set book and numbering a table is 1.1...second chapter 2.1.....and one chapter just in one I need numbering my table just table 1 table 2....
any help ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{book}
```

Comment: \appendix
\setcounter{exx}{0}

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to change the table counter formatting command `\thetable`, which is very likely `\thechapter.\arabic{table}` to `\arabic{table}` only and reset to the old behaviour it after the relevant chapter. This can be with the `\let` saving mechanism.

Some more explanation: The `\newcounter` command allows for an optional 2nd argument which contains the driver counter, i.e. for using `book.cls` the relevant command was

```
\newcounter{table}{chapter}
```

meaning that the table counter is reset to zero if the chapter counter is increased (by `\stepcounter` or `\refstepcounter`). This is one part of the coupling. The other part is the output of the table counter, which is in this case `\thechapter.\arabic{table}` by default.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{book}



\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\begin{table}
\caption{dummy one}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{dummy two}
\end{table}

\let\latexthetable\thetable  % save original version
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}} % renewcommand

\chapter{Second}

\begin{table}
\caption{dummy one}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{dummy two}
\end{table}

\let\thetable\latexthetable % switch back to original version

\chapter{Third}

\begin{table}
\caption{dummy one}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{dummy two}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```